# Compiling Error with If when i Edit a Row on my DataBase

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code where i find a row, edit some data and replace the data with the new one, but, as i tried to make and IF and Else statement so the person can lookup by ID or Surname, i have a compiling error... and i can´t find the problem with it... Hope any of you have better eyes than i do.

```
Private Sub btnPerso3_Click()

    'declare the variables
    Dim findvalue As Range
    Dim cNum As Integer
    Dim Registros As Worksheet
    'error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Registros = Hoja4
    'check for values
    'If BLeg3.Value = "" Or BApe3.Value = "" Then
    'MsgBox "No hay datos para modificar"
    'Exit Sub
    'End If
    'Buscar por Legajo la fila para editar
    If BApe3.Value = "" Then Set findvalue = Registros.Range("A:A"). _
        Find(What:=BLeg3.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    'update the values
    findvalue.Offset(0, 4) = Fech3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 0) = Leg3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 1) = Ape3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 2) = Nomb3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 3) = Pues3.Value

ElseIf BLeg3.Value = "" Then Set findvalue = Registros.Range("B:B") _
        .Find(What:=BApe3.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    'update the values
    findvalue.Offset(0, 3) = Fech3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, -1) = Leg3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 0) = Ape3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 1) = Nomb3.Value
    findvalue.Offset(0, 2) = Pues3.Value
    MsgBox "Se han modificado correctamente los datos"

End If

'error block
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

errHandler:
'show error information in a messagebox
MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & _
       "The error number is: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```

Comment: First step: use this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to fix your indentation :-)

Comment: Next step: make your `If` multi-line form by moving the `Set findvalue = Registros.Range("A:A"). _` to a new line.

Comment: What error is showing up and on what row?

Comment: @FaneDuru - `Else without If` on the `ElseIf` line.

Comment: Pres Enter after this piece of line code: `If BApe3.Value = "" Then`.  The rest of the code:  `Set findvalue = Registros...` must be on the next line.

Comment: Works fine now after i moved the set findvalue to the next line, thought it wont change but it did.

Comment: Please define "works fine". Does the code do what expected, or only the error message disappeared?

Comment: The code does what it should now, without errors!

Comment: Good! All the credit goes to @BigBen who firstly made the suggestion. I saw it after I made my comment. I must confess, I did not analize the code logic...

Comment: If the Id is really an Identifier, it shouldn't ever change - if it does then you'd end not matching the original row.  If it doesn't ever change then there's no need for the surname match.  A better pattern is to store the source row number when the user begins the edit, then restore to that row.

Comment: @BigBen: The link you posted does not go anywhere... It returns „500 - Internal server error.”. Would be that only a temporary server problem?

Comment: @FaneDuru - sounds like a problem on your side.

Comment: @BigBen:  I am able to go wherever I want, pressing all the buttons. Only the link from the page (http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp) does not work, returning the error I mentioned before...

Comment: @FaneDuru - google "RubberduckVBA indentation"

Comment: @BigBen: Google brought me at the same page. Thanks, anyhow! I will keep digging deeper...

Comment: @FaneDuru - should be rubberduckvba.com/indentation. **Edit** now I see what you mean...

Comment: @BigBen:  There I was brought all the time. I was talking about the link behind „ Smart Indenter” link within the page. But, never-mind, I will find is in a way...

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: Thanks! I will give it a shut and I'll be patient till the site will be OK updated...

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon:  Ups... Only now I understood. English is not my best point... Anyhow, I have a 64 bit Office installed and I could not install the 32 bit version. Thanks, anyhow!

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: Thanks! I know. I used Rubberduck on my previous laptop. I have a new one and I did not install everything I need, yet...

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to find the correct row first, then have a single block of code for transferring the data:

```
Private Sub btnPerso3_Click()

    Dim Registros As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo errHandler 'error handling

    Set Registros = Hoja4

    'if a search term is entered, see if there's a matching row
    If BApe3.Value <> "" Then
        m = Application.Match(BApe3.Value, Registros.Range("B:B"), 0)
    ElseIf BLeg3.Value <> "" Then
        m = Application.Match(BLeg3.Value, Registros.Range("A:A"), 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "No search value entered!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not IsError(m) Then
        'found the matching row: update
        With Registros.Rows(m)
            .Cells(5).Value = Fech3.Value
            .Cells(1).Value = Leg3.Value
            .Cells(2).Value = Ape3.Value
            .Cells(3).Value = Nomb3.Value
            .Cells(4).Value = Pues3.Value
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No match found!"
    End If

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    'show error information in a messagebox
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & _
           "The error number is: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```